# Creating 3D Buildings for Google Earth

Tags: software-recommendations, google-earth, 3d, references

I want to learn creating real 3D buildings to use them for google earth.

What is the best software for that?

What are the best books/tutorials to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest start point is Google SketchUp.

http://download.cnet.com/SketchUp/3000-6677_4-10257337.html

You will find most of the required materials online.